# bro-ids logstash filter not working

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, bro

I've set up an ELK stack on centos 7, and are forwarding logs from a freebsd 11 host which runs bro.  However my filters are not working to correctly parse the bro logs.

This is the current set up:

freebsd filebeat client

filebeat.yml

```
filebeat:
registry_file: /var/run/.filebeat
prospectors:
-
  paths:
    - /var/log/messages
    - /var/log/maillog
    - /var/log/auth.log
    - /var/log/cron
    - /var/log/debug.log
    - /var/log/devd.log
    - /var/log/ppp.log
    - /var/log/netatalk.log
    - /var/log/setuid.today
    - /var/log/utx.log
    - /var/log/rkhunter.log
    - /var/log/userlog
    - /var/log/sendmail.st
    - /var/log/xferlog
  input_type: log
  document_type: syslog

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/app_stats.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_app_stats

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/communication.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_communication

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/conn.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_conn

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/dhcp.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_dhcp

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/dns.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_dns

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/dpd.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_dpd

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/files.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_files

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/ftp.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_ftp

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/http.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_http

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/known_certs.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_app_known_certs

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/known_hosts.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_known_hosts

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/known_services.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_known_services

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/notice.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_notice

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/smtp.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_smtp

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/software.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_software

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/ssh.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_ssh

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/ssl.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_ssl

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/weird.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_weird

-
  paths:
    - /var/log/bro/current/x509.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: bro_x509
```

then on the centos ELK server I have 4 configs:

/etc/logstash/conf.d/02-beats-input.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
```

/etc/logstash/conf.d/10-syslog-filter.conf

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
  add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
  add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

/etc/logstash/conf.d/20-bro-ids-filter.conf

```
filter {
    # bro_app_stats ######################
      if [type] == "bro_app" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<ts_delta>(.*?))\t(?<app>(.*?))\t(?<uniq_hosts>(.*?))\t(?<hits>(.*?))\t(?<bytes>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_conn ######################
      if [type] == "bro_conn" {
        grok {
            match => [ 
                "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<uid>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t(?<proto>(.*?))\t(?<service>(.*?))\t(?<duration>(.*?))\t(?<orig_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<resp_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<conn_state>(.*?))\t(?<local_orig>(.*?))\t(?<missed_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<history>(.*?))\t(?<orig_pkts>(.*?))\t(?<orig_ip_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<resp_pkts>(.*?))\t(?<resp_ip_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<tunnel_parents>(.*?))\t(?<orig_cc>(.*?))\t(?<resp_cc>(.*?))\t(?<sensorname>(.*))",
                "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<uid>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t(?<proto>(.*?))\t(?<service>(.*?))\t(?<duration>(.*?))\t(?<orig_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<resp_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<conn_state>(.*?))\t(?<local_orig>(.*?))\t(?<missed_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<history>(.*?))\t(?<orig_pkts>(.*?))\t(?<orig_ip_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<resp_pkts>(.*?))\t(?<resp_ip_bytes>(.*?))\t(%{NOTSPACE:tunnel_parents})"
            ]
        }
      }

    # bro_notice ######################
      if [type] == "bro_notice" {
        grok { 
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<uid>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t(?<fuid>(.*?))\t(?<file_mime_type>(.*?))\t(?<file_desc>(.*?))\t(?<proto>(.*?))\t(?<note>(.*?))\t(?<msg>(.*?))\t(?<sub>(.*?))\t(?<src>(.*?))\t(?<dst>(.*?))\t(?<p>(.*?))\t(?<n>(.*?))\t(?<peer_descr>(.*?))\t(?<actions>(.*?))\t(?<suppress_for>(.*?))\t(?<dropped>(.*?))\t(?<remote_location.country_code>(.*?))\t(?<remote_location.region>(.*?))\t(?<remote_location.city>(.*?))\t(?<remote_location.latitude>(.*?))\t(?<remote_location.longitude>(.*))" ]
        }
      }


    # bro_dhcp ######################
      if [type] == "bro_dhcp" {
        grok { 
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<uid>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t(?<mac>(.*?))\t(?<assigned_ip>(.*?))\t(?<lease_time>(.*?))\t(?<trans_id>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_dns ######################
      if [type] == "bro_dns" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<uid>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t(?<proto>(.*?))\t(?<trans_id>(.*?))\t(?<query>(.*?))\t(?<qclass>(.*?))\t(?<qclass_name>(.*?))\t(?<qtype>(.*?))\t(?<qtype_name>(.*?))\t(?<rcode>(.*?))\t(?<rcode_name>(.*?))\t(?<AA>(.*?))\t(?<TC>(.*?))\t(?<RD>(.*?))\t(?<RA>(.*?))\t(?<Z>(.*?))\t(?<answers>(.*?))\t(?<TTLs>(.*?))\t(?<rejected>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_software ######################
      if [type] == "bro_software" {
        grok { 
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<bro_host>(.*?))\t(?<host_p>(.*?))\t(?<software_type>(.*?))\t(?<name>(.*?))\t(?<version.major>(.*?))\t(?<version.minor>(.*?))\t(?<version.minor2>(.*?))\t(?<version.minor3>(.*?))\t(?<version.addl>(.*?))\t(?<unparsed_version>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_dpd ######################
      if [type] == "bro_dpd" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<uid>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t(?<proto>(.*?))\t(?<analyzer>(.*?))\t(?<failure_reason>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_files ######################
      if [type] == "bro_files" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<fuid>(.*?))\t(?<tx_hosts>(.*?))\t(?<rx_hosts>(.*?))\t(?<conn_uids>(.*?))\t(?<source>(.*?))\t(?<depth>(.*?))\t(?<analyzers>(.*?))\t(?<mime_type>(.*?))\t(?<filename>(.*?))\t(?<duration>(.*?))\t(?<local_orig>(.*?))\t(?<is_orig>(.*?))\t(?<seen_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<total_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<missing_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<overflow_bytes>(.*?))\t(?<timedout>(.*?))\t(?<parent_fuid>(.*?))\t(?<md5>(.*?))\t(?<sha1>(.*?))\t(?<sha256>(.*?))\t(?<extracted>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_http ######################
      if [type] == "bro_http" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<uid>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t(?<trans_depth>(.*?))\t(?<method>(.*?))\t(?<bro_host>(.*?))\t(?<uri>(.*?))\t(?<referrer>(.*?))\t(?<user_agent>(.*?))\t(?<request_body_len>(.*?))\t(?<response_body_len>(.*?))\t(?<status_code>(.*?))\t(?<status_msg>(.*?))\t(?<info_code>(.*?))\t(?<info_msg>(.*?))\t(?<filename>(.*?))\t(?<http_tags>(.*?))\t(?<username>(.*?))\t(?<password>(.*?))\t(?<proxied>(.*?))\t(?<orig_fuids>(.*?))\t(?<orig_mime_types>(.*?))\t(?<resp_fuids>(.*?))\t(?<resp_mime_types>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_known_certs ######################
      if [type] == "bro_known_certs" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<bro_host>(.*?))\t(?<port_num>(.*?))\t(?<subject>(.*?))\t(?<issuer_subject>(.*?))\t(?<serial>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_known_hosts ######################
      if [type] == "bro_known_hosts" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<bro_host>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_known_services ######################
      if [type] == "bro_known_services" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<bro_host>(.*?))\t(?<port_num>(.*?))\t(?<port_proto>(.*?))\t(?<service>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_ssh ######################
      if [type] == "bro_ssh" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<uid>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t(?<status>(.*?))\t(?<direction>(.*?))\t(?<client>(.*?))\t(?<server>(.*?))\t(?<remote_location.country_code>(.*?))\t(?<remote_location.region>(.*?))\t(?<remote_location.city>(.*?))\t(?<remote_location.latitude>(.*?))\t(?<remote_location.longitude>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_ssl ######################
      if [type] == "bro_ssl" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<uid>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t(?<version>(.*?))\t(?<cipher>(.*?))\t(?<server_name>(.*?))\t(?<session_id>(.*?))\t(?<subject>(.*?))\t(?<issuer_subject>(.*?))\t(?<not_valid_before>(.*?))\t(?<not_valid_after>(.*?))\t(?<last_alert>(.*?))\t(?<client_subject>(.*?))\t(?<client_issuer_subject>(.*?))\t(?<cert_hash>(.*?))\t(?<validation_status>(.*))" ]
        }
      }

    # bro_weird ######################
    if [type] == "bro_weird" {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t(?<uid>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t(?<name>(.*?))\t(?<addl>(.*?))\t(?<notice>(.*?))\t(?<peer>(.*))" ]
            }
    }

    # bro_x509 #######################
    if [type] == "bro_x509" {
        csv {

          #x509.log:#fields ts  id  certificate.version certificate.serial  certificate.subject certificate.issuer  certificate.not_valid_before    certificate.not_valid_after certificate.key_alg certificate.sig_alg certificate.key_type    certificate.key_length  certificate.exponent    certificate.curve   san.dns san.uri san.email   san.ip  basic_constraints.ca    basic_constraints.path_len
          columns => ["ts","id","certificate.version","certificate.serial","certificate.subject","icertificate.issuer","certificate.not_valid_before","certificate.not_valid_after","certificate.key_alg","certificate.sig_alg","certificate.key_type","certificate.key_length","certificate.exponent","certificate.curve","san.dns","san.uri","san.email","san.ip","basic_constraints.ca","basic_constraints.path_len"]

          #If you use a custom delimiter, change the following value in between the quotes to your delimiter. Otherwise, leave the next line alone.
          separator => "    "
        }

        #Let's convert our timestamp into the 'ts' field, so we can use Kibana features natively
        date {
          match => [ "ts", "UNIX" ]
        }

      }

    if [type]== "bro_intel" {
      grok {
        match => [ "message", "(?<ts>(.*?))\t%{DATA:uid}\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\t%{DATA:fuid}\t%{DATA:file_mime_type}\t%{DATA:file_desc}\t(?<seen.indicator>(.*?))\t(?<seen.indicator_type>(.*?))\t(?<seen.where>(.*?))\t%{NOTSPACE:sources}" ]
     }
   }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "ts", "UNIX" ]
  }
}

filter {
  if "bro" in [type] {
    if [id.orig_h] {
      mutate {
        add_field => [ "senderbase_lookup", "http://www.senderbase.org/lookup/?search_string=%{id.orig_h}" ]
        add_field => [ "CBL_lookup", "http://cbl.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi?ip=%{id.orig_h}" ]
        add_field => [ "Spamhaus_lookup", "http://www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=%{id.orig_h}" ]
      }
    }
    mutate {
      add_tag => [ "bro" ]
    }
    mutate {
      convert => [ "id.orig_p", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "id.resp_p", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "orig_bytes", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "resp_bytes", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "missed_bytes", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "orig_pkts", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "orig_ip_bytes", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "resp_pkts", "integer" ]
      convert => [ "resp_ip_bytes", "integer" ]
    }
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "bro_conn" {
    #The following makes use of the translate filter (stash contrib) to convert conn_state into human text. Saves having to look up values for packet introspection
    translate {
      field => "conn_state"
      destination => "conn_state_full"
      dictionary => [ 
        "S0", "Connection attempt seen, no reply",
        "S1", "Connection established, not terminated",
        "S2", "Connection established and close attempt by originator seen (but no reply from responder)",
        "S3", "Connection established and close attempt by responder seen (but no reply from originator)",
        "SF", "Normal SYN/FIN completion",
        "REJ", "Connection attempt rejected",
        "RSTO", "Connection established, originator aborted (sent a RST)",
        "RSTR", "Established, responder aborted",
        "RSTOS0", "Originator sent a SYN followed by a RST, we never saw a SYN-ACK from the responder",
        "RSTRH", "Responder sent a SYN ACK followed by a RST, we never saw a SYN from the (purported) originator",
        "SH", "Originator sent a SYN followed by a FIN, we never saw a SYN ACK from the responder (hence the connection was 'half' open)",
        "SHR", "Responder sent a SYN ACK followed by a FIN, we never saw a SYN from the originator",
        "OTH", "No SYN seen, just midstream traffic (a 'partial connection' that was not later closed)" 
      ]
    }
  }
}
# Resolve @source_host to FQDN if possible if missing for some types of ging using source_host_ip from above
filter {
  if [id.orig_h] {
    if ![id.orig_h-resolved] {
      mutate {
        add_field => [ "id.orig_h-resolved", "%{id.orig_h}" ]
      }
      dns {
        reverse => [ "id.orig_h-resolved" ]
        action => "replace"
      }
    }
  }
}
filter {
  if [id.resp_h] {
    if ![id.resp_h-resolved] {
      mutate {
        add_field => [ "id.resp_h-resolved", "%{id.resp_h}" ]
      }
      dns {
        reverse => [ "id.resp_h-resolved" ]
        action => "replace"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and /etc/logstash/conf.d/30-elasticsearch-output.conf

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

I've leveraged this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mrlesmithjr/571ff9764a601efdb493) and tailored it to my configuration.  While running I get the following error in /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log:

```
[2016-11-06T15:30:36,961][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] ########\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_dhcp\" {\n\t\tgrok { \n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<uid>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\\t(?<mac>(.*?))\\t(?<assigned_ip>(.*?))\\t(?<lease_time>(.*?))\\t(?<trans_id>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_dns ######################\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_dns\" {\n\t\tgrok {\n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<uid>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\\t(?<proto>(.*?))\\t(?<trans_id>(.*?))\\t(?<query>(.*?))\\t(?<qclass>(.*?))\\t(?<qclass_name>(.*?))\\t(?<qtype>(.*?))\\t(?<qtype_name>(.*?))\\t(?<rcode>(.*?))\\t(?<rcode_name>(.*?))\\t(?<AA>(.*?))\\t(?<TC>(.*?))\\t(?<RD>(.*?))\\t(?<RA>(.*?))\\t(?<Z>(.*?))\\t(?<answers>(.*?))\\t(?<TTLs>(.*?))\\t(?<rejected>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_software ######################\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_software\" {\n\t\tgrok { \n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<bro_host>(.*?))\\t(?<host_p>(.*?))\\t(?<software_type>(.*?))\\t(?<name>(.*?))\\t(?<version.major>(.*?))\\t(?<version.minor>(.*?))\\t(?<version.minor2>(.*?))\\t(?<version.minor3>(.*?))\\t(?<version.addl>(.*?))\\t(?<unparsed_version>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_dpd ######################\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_dpd\" {\n\t\tgrok {\n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<uid>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\\t(?<proto>(.*?))\\t(?<analyzer>(.*?))\\t(?<failure_reason>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_files ######################\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_files\" {\n\t\tgrok {\n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<fuid>(.*?))\\t(?<tx_hosts>(.*?))\\t(?<rx_hosts>(.*?))\\t(?<conn_uids>(.*?))\\t(?<source>(.*?))\\t(?<depth>(.*?))\\t(?<analyzers>(.*?))\\t(?<mime_type>(.*?))\\t(?<filename>(.*?))\\t(?<duration>(.*?))\\t(?<local_orig>(.*?))\\t(?<is_orig>(.*?))\\t(?<seen_bytes>(.*?))\\t(?<total_bytes>(.*?))\\t(?<missing_bytes>(.*?))\\t(?<overflow_bytes>(.*?))\\t(?<timedout>(.*?))\\t(?<parent_fuid>(.*?))\\t(?<md5>(.*?))\\t(?<sha1>(.*?))\\t(?<sha256>(.*?))\\t(?<extracted>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_http ######################\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_http\" {\n\t\tgrok {\n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<uid>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\\t(?<trans_depth>(.*?))\\t(?<method>(.*?))\\t(?<bro_host>(.*?))\\t(?<uri>(.*?))\\t(?<referrer>(.*?))\\t(?<user_agent>(.*?))\\t(?<request_body_len>(.*?))\\t(?<response_body_len>(.*?))\\t(?<status_code>(.*?))\\t(?<status_msg>(.*?))\\t(?<info_code>(.*?))\\t(?<info_msg>(.*?))\\t(?<filename>(.*?))\\t(?<http_tags>(.*?))\\t(?<username>(.*?))\\t(?<password>(.*?))\\t(?<proxied>(.*?))\\t(?<orig_fuids>(.*?))\\t(?<orig_mime_types>(.*?))\\t(?<resp_fuids>(.*?))\\t(?<resp_mime_types>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_known_certs ######################\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_known_certs\" {\n\t\tgrok {\n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<bro_host>(.*?))\\t(?<port_num>(.*?))\\t(?<subject>(.*?))\\t(?<issuer_subject>(.*?))\\t(?<serial>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_known_hosts ######################\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_known_hosts\" {\n\t\tgrok {\n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<bro_host>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_known_services ######################\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_known_services\" {\n\t\tgrok {\n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<bro_host>(.*?))\\t(?<port_num>(.*?))\\t(?<port_proto>(.*?))\\t(?<service>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_ssh ######################\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_ssh\" {\n\t\tgrok {\n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<uid>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\\t(?<status>(.*?))\\t(?<direction>(.*?))\\t(?<client>(.*?))\\t(?<server>(.*?))\\t(?<remote_location.country_code>(.*?))\\t(?<remote_location.region>(.*?))\\t(?<remote_location.city>(.*?))\\t(?<remote_location.latitude>(.*?))\\t(?<remote_location.longitude>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_ssl ######################\n\t  if [type] == \"bro_ssl\" {\n\t\tgrok {\n\t\t  match => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<uid>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\\t(?<version>(.*?))\\t(?<cipher>(.*?))\\t(?<server_name>(.*?))\\t(?<session_id>(.*?))\\t(?<subject>(.*?))\\t(?<issuer_subject>(.*?))\\t(?<not_valid_before>(.*?))\\t(?<not_valid_after>(.*?))\\t(?<last_alert>(.*?))\\t(?<client_subject>(.*?))\\t(?<client_issuer_subject>(.*?))\\t(?<cert_hash>(.*?))\\t(?<validation_status>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t  }\n\n\t# bro_weird ######################\n\tif [type] == \"bro_weird\" {\n\t\tgrok {\n\t\t\tmatch => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t(?<uid>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\\t(?<name>(.*?))\\t(?<addl>(.*?))\\t(?<notice>(.*?))\\t(?<peer>(.*))\" ]\n\t\t\t}\n\t}\n\t\n\t# bro_x509 #######################\n\tif [type] == \"bro_x509\" {\n\t\tcsv {\n\t\n\t\t  #x509.log:#fields\tts\tid\tcertificate.version\tcertificate.serial\tcertificate.subject\tcertificate.issuer\tcertificate.not_valid_before\tcertificate.not_valid_after\tcertificate.key_alg\tcertificate.sig_alg\tcertificate.key_type\tcertificate.key_length\tcertificate.exponent\tcertificate.curve\tsan.dns\tsan.uri\tsan.email\tsan.ip\tbasic_constraints.ca\tbasic_constraints.path_len\n\t\t  columns => [\"ts\",\"id\",\"certificate.version\",\"certificate.serial\",\"certificate.subject\",\"icertificate.issuer\",\"certificate.not_valid_before\",\"certificate.not_valid_after\",\"certificate.key_alg\",\"certificate.sig_alg\",\"certificate.key_type\",\"certificate.key_length\",\"certificate.exponent\",\"certificate.curve\",\"san.dns\",\"san.uri\",\"san.email\",\"san.ip\",\"basic_constraints.ca\",\"basic_constraints.path_len\"]\n\t\n\t\t  #If you use a custom delimiter, change the following value in between the quotes to your delimiter. Otherwise, leave the next line alone.\n\t\t  separator => \"\t\"\n\t\t}\n\t\n\t\t#Let's convert our timestamp into the 'ts' field, so we can use Kibana features natively\n\t\tdate {\n\t\t  match => [ \"ts\", \"UNIX\" ]\n\t\t}\n\t\n\t  }\n\t\n\tif [type]== \"bro_intel\" {\n\t  grok {\n\t\tmatch => [ \"message\", \"(?<ts>(.*?))\\t%{DATA:uid}\\t(?<id.orig_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.orig_p>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_h>(.*?))\\t(?<id.resp_p>(.*?))\\t%{DATA:fuid}\\t%{DATA:file_mime_type}\\t%{DATA:file_desc}\\t(?<seen.indicator>(.*?))\\t(?<seen.indicator_type>(.*?))\\t(?<seen.where>(.*?))\\t%{NOTSPACE:sources}\" ]\n\t }\n   }\n  }\n  date {\n\tmatch => [ \"ts\", \"UNIX\" ]\n  }\n}\n\nfilter {\n  if \"bro\" in [type] {\n\tif [id.orig_h] {\n\t  mutate {\n\t\tadd_field => [ \"senderbase_lookup\", \"http://www.senderbase.org/lookup/?search_string=%{id.orig_h}\" ]\n\t\tadd_field => [ \"CBL_lookup\", \"http://cbl.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi?ip=%{id.orig_h}\" ]\n\t\tadd_field => [ \"Spamhaus_lookup\", \"http://www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=%{id.orig_h}\" ]\n\t  }\n\t}\n\tmutate {\n\t  add_tag => [ \"bro\" ]\n\t}\n\tmutate {\n\t  convert => [ \"id.orig_p\", \"integer\" ]\n\t  convert => [ \"id.resp_p\", \"integer\" ]\n\t  convert => [ \"orig_bytes\", \"integer\" ]\n\t  convert => [ \"resp_bytes\", \"integer\" ]\n\t  convert => [ \"missed_bytes\", \"integer\" ]\n\t  convert => [ \"orig_pkts\", \"integer\" ]\n\t  convert => [ \"orig_ip_bytes\", \"integer\" ]\n\t  convert => [ \"resp_pkts\", \"integer\" ]\n\t  convert => [ \"resp_ip_bytes\", \"integer\" ]\n\t}\n  }\n}\n\nfilter {\n  if [type] == \"bro_conn\" {\n\t#The following makes use of the translate filter (stash contrib) to convert conn_state into human text. Saves having to look up values for packet introspection\n\ttranslate {\n\t  field => \"conn_state\"\n\t  destination => \"conn_state_full\"\n\t  dictionary => [ \n\t\t\"S0\", \"Connection attempt seen, no reply\",\n\t\t\"S1\", \"Connection established, not terminated\",\n\t\t\"S2\", \"Connection established and close attempt by originator seen (but no reply from responder)\",\n\t\t\"S3\", \"Connection established and close attempt by responder seen (but no reply from originator)\",\n\t\t\"SF\", \"Normal SYN/FIN completion\",\n\t\t\"REJ\", \"Connection attempt rejected\",\n\t\t\"RSTO\", \"Connection established, originator aborted (sent a RST)\",\n\t\t\"RSTR\", \"Established, responder aborted\",\n\t\t\"RSTOS0\", \"Originator sent a SYN followed by a RST, we never saw a SYN-ACK from the responder\",\n\t\t\"RSTRH\", \"Responder sent a SYN ACK followed by a RST, we never saw a SYN from the (purported) originator\",\n\t\t\"SH\", \"Originator sent a SYN followed by a FIN, we never saw a SYN ACK from the responder (hence the connection was 'half' open)\",\n\t\t\"SHR\", \"Responder sent a SYN ACK followed by a FIN, we never saw a SYN from the originator\",\n\t\t\"OTH\", \"No SYN seen, just midstream traffic (a 'partial connection' that was not later closed)\" \n\t  ]\n\t}\n  }\n}\n# Resolve @source_host to FQDN if possible if missing for some types of ging using source_host_ip from above\nfilter {\n  if [id.orig_h] {\n\tif ![id.orig_h-resolved] {\n\t  mutate {\n\t\tadd_field => [ \"id.orig_h-resolved\", \"%{id.orig_h}\" ]\n\t  }\n\t  dns {\n\t\treverse => [ \"id.orig_h-resolved\" ]\n\t\taction => \"replace\"\n\t  }\n\t}\n  }\n}\nfilter {\n  if [id.resp_h] {\n\tif ![id.resp_h-resolved] {\n\t  mutate {\n\t\tadd_field => [ \"id.resp_h-resolved\", \"%{id.resp_h}\" ]\n\t  }\n\t  dns {\n\t\treverse => [ \"id.resp_h-resolved\" ]\n\t\taction => \"replace\"\n\t  }\n\t}\n  }\n}\n\noutput {\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => [\"localhost:9200\"]\n    #sniffing => true\n    manage_template => false\n    index => \"%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}\"\n    document_type => \"%{[@metadata][type]}\"\n  }\n}\n\n", :reason=>"Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 158, column 3 (byte 8746) after "}
```

To the best of my ability I've reviewed my logstash configuration and I can't see any errors.  Can anyone help me figure out whats wrong with it?

I'm running
logstash.noarch                    1:5.0.0-1                      @elasticsearch
elasticsearch.noarch               5.0.0-1                        @elasticsearch

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you match the open curly brace at the top of 20-bro-ids-filter.conf, you'll see it matches with close curly brace just before your date{} stanza.  That puts date{} outside the filter{}, generating the message that it's expecting input{}, output{}, or filter{}.